# Regular Expressions in OCaml

Tags: regex, module, linker, ocaml

I want to use *regexps* in OCaml and it seems that `Str` module provides these functionalities.

So I tried with a simple program:

```
open Str
let regx = regexp "."
```

but it gives me the following error

> File "lol.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
>   Error: Error while linking lol.cmo:
>   Reference to undefined global `Str'

As if module is not present but if I remove `open Str` it says that `regexp` is an unbound value.

I don't get what kind of issue it is, `Str` should be a standard module (according to http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/old-311/libref/Str.html) so I'm clueless.. the only think I thought is that signature (`mli`) is present but implementation (`ml`) is not.

I'm running `Objective Caml version 3.11.0` according to `ocaml` tool.

Can anyone help me figuring this out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can avoid it, you *really* don't want to use the `Str` module.  Its API is non-reentrant, leading to all manner of problems.  Fortunately, PCRE has good OCaml bindings at: http://www.ocaml.info/home/ocaml_sources.html  You might also want to check out Mikmatch for syntax support on top of the PCRE engine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libstr.html):

> Programs that use the str library must be linked as follows:
>
> ```
> ocamlc other options str.cma other files
> ocamlopt other options str.cmxa other files
> ```

Answer (score 24):

Or you can put

```
#load "str.cma";;
```

if you are doing it in the interpreter

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful while trying from toplevel

Comment: hi @newacct, can you please explain why the ocamllex display an error when i put that line in 1st line in my lexer.mll ? the error is: Reference to undefined global `Str'  ....

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the `Str` module there's also [`Re2`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.24.01/doc/re2/Regex.html).

1. Install it using `opam install re2`
2. Use the module in `your_file.ml` like this:

   ```
   open Re2.Std
   open Re2.Infix
   let change input_text = Re2.rewrite_exn ~/"change this" "to that" input_text
   let () = printf "%s" (change "change this")
   ```
3. Compile with `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package re2 -package core -tag thread your_file.byte`

Comment: FYI - It appears that Jane Street have deprecated `Re2` as of 2020. See https://blog.janestreet.com/what-the-interns-have-wrought-2020/ and https://github.com/janestreet/re2/issues/26#issuecomment-395870146