# Substring check in Ocaml

Tags: string, ocaml

Can someone help me in coding an effective substring check in OCaml? Given two strings, check whether the first one contains the second one?

Using the `Str` module, can we do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
let contains s1 s2 =
    let re = Str.regexp_string s2
    in
        try ignore (Str.search_forward re s1 0); true
        with Not_found -> false
```

Here are some tests of the function:

```
# contains "abcde" "bc";;
- : bool = true
# contains "abcde" "bd";;
- : bool = false
# contains "abcde" "b.";;
- : bool = false
# contains "ab.de" "b.";;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: this wont work if `s2` has special regex character sequences in it, like `.`. You'll have to call, `Str.quote s2` first.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  The purpose of `regexp_string` is to match exactly a particular string.  It presumably does quoting internally. My tests show that this code works OK.

Comment: contains is a bad name, cause it has already another meaning in extension libraries.

Comment: To use this approach, the `Str` library must be linked:
https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/libstr.html
or else you get an Error. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221067/regular-expressions-in-ocaml

Answer (score 0):

```
let contains_substring search target =
    String.substr_index search target <> None
```

Comment: substr_index is not in the stdlib. is this from a different lib?

Comment: substr_index it's in Base.String