# OCAML - strings and substrings

Tags: string, ocaml, substring

Could someone help me to write a function that checks if a string is a substring of another string?

(there can be more than only 2 strings)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'there can be more than only 2 strings'? As for string/substring tests see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8373460/520394.

Comment: Want to show us your attempts so we can help you more efficiently? Help us help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `String` module:

```
let contains s1 s2 =
  try
    let len = String.length s2 in
    for i = 0 to String.length s1 - len do
      if String.sub s1 i len = s2 then raise Exit
    done;
    false
  with Exit -> true
```

With `Str` module, like @barti_ddu said check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8373460/520394):

```
let contains s1 s2 =
    let re = Str.regexp_string s2 in
    try 
       ignore (Str.search_forward re s1 0); 
       true
    with Not_found -> false
```

Comment: The memory usage for the `String`-based one is scary !

Comment: Yes, but I thought that the code would be quite simple to understand for a new OCaml user :-)

Answer (score 4):

With Batteries, you can use [String.exists](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatString.html#VALexists). It also exists in ExtLib: [String.exists](http://ocaml-extlib.googlecode.com/svn/doc/apiref/ExtString.String.html#VALexists).

Answer (score 2):

A `String`-based alternative to cago's answer that might have better performance and lower memory usage:

```
let is_substring string substring = 
  let ssl = String.length substring and sl = String.length string in 
  if ssl = 0 || ssl > sl then false else 
    let max = sl - ssl and clone = String.create ssl in
    let rec check pos = 
      pos <= max && (
        String.blit string pos clone 0 ssl ; clone = substring 
        || check (String.index_from string (succ pos) substring.[0])
      )
    in             
    try check (String.index string substring.[0])
    with Not_found -> false
```

Answer (score -17):

```
String str="hello world";


System.out.println(str.contains("world"));//true

System.out.println(str.contains("world1"));//false
```

Comment: the question was about ocaml not java