# ReasonML equivalent of OCaml ExtString.exists

Tags: string, reason

ReasonML is built upon OCaml, and much of OCaml stdlib is available on ReasonML. However, [ExtString](http://ocaml-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/ExtString.String.html) is not one of them.

I'm in need of using ExtString.exists to verify if a substring `sub` exists within a string `str`. I know that I can make my own function, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373460/substring-check-in-ocaml), but I'm wondering if there's any way I can import ExtString from or OCaml, or if there's a equivalend module on stdlib that I didn't realize.

Comment: Are you compiling your ReasonML to javascript or byte/native code?

Comment: @NickZuber Javascript

Comment: But could you, please, provide an answer to both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling to JavaScript you have [`Js.String.includes`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.String.html#VALincludes) as replacement for `Str.exists` specifically, and more generally I think the `Js.String` module should cover most of `ExtString`.

When compiling to native you can just use `ExtString`. Reason is just an alternative syntax for OCaml, everything else works exactly the same.