# OCaml v5.0, "Module `Str' is unavailable"

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune, ocaml-5

Im trying to use the Ocaml Str library in Ocaml v5.0 (for regexp) by importing using "open Str" but I keep getting this error

"Module `Str' is unavailable"

followed by this alert

"
OCaml's lib directory layout changed in 5.0. The str subdirectory has been
automatically added to the search path, but you should add -I +str to the
command-line to silence this alert (e.g. by adding str to the list of
libraries in your dune file, or adding use_str to your _tags file for
ocamlbuild, or using -package str for ocamlfind).
"

I'm new to OCaml, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried putting "add -I +str" into the command line however I got another error.
I'm not sure how to add a library to my dune file so I haven't attempted this yet.

Comment: My guess: don't put "add -I +str", just put "-I +str".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Str library is a separate library, and it is not part of the standard library. Moreover, libraries are not imported with open statements in OCaml.

You need to add a `libraries` stanza to your dune file:

```
(libraries str)
```

You can ignore the alert which is meant for previous users of the `str` library that were relying on the fact that the `str` library was previously co-located with the standard library.

It is also generally advise to avoid the `str` library when possible and use one of the other regexp library from opam.

Comment: Further reading with some details on why `str` is being advised against.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221067/regular-expressions-in-ocaml